# Turning on Index Viewer for SPE

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have really given it a go before I posted here, but I am trying to turn on the Index Viewer for SPE. The gitbook doco says it exists, shows it not being in the menu, but no info on how to put it in the menu. Can someone lead me in the right direction to enable it.

Thank you.

https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules/integration-points/toolbox

Comment: I didn't see "Authorable Reports for SPE" on the Sitecore Marketplace, but the download is available on the Sitecore Powershell Extensions github releases page:
https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/releases The latest version as of this writing is named Sitecore.PowerShell.Extensions.-.Authorable.Reports-4.5.zip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reports are not a part of default **SPE** module package.

To get it:

- go to marketplace 
  [Sitecore Powershell Extensions module](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx?sc_lang=en)
- download: 
  **Authorable Reports for SPE 4.2** (assuming you are using **SPE 4.2**)

Once you install this package you will see additional button in the **PowerShell Toolbox**

[image]

You will find more info about this feature in this video: [Unofficial Sitecore 8 Training Webinar Series - Session 5](https://youtu.be/6n7pShsFHLY?t=9m24s), where Michael West describes what you can do with that and why this is not a part of default package.

Comment: Thank you very much Alan. I did see it live on Session 5 but didn't note on how Mike said to turn it on. Thanks again for your help on this.